# counting number of points and displaying result in ggplot (for a confusion matrix)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some binary classification data and I want to plot the confusion matrix. What I want to do is add at the centre of each quadrant the count of points (just like in an actual 2x2 confusion matrix).

For illustration I use the `iris` dataset and remove the Species `setosa` to make it into a binary classification task.

```
data(iris)
iris <- iris %>% 
  filter(Species != "setosa") %>% 
  mutate(
    Species_to_predict = case_when(
      Species == "versicolor" ~ 0,
      Species == "virginica" ~ 1
    )
  )

myLogitModel <- glm(formula = Species_to_predict ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width,
    data = iris, family = "binomial")

summary(myLogitModel)

myPreds <- predict(object = myLogitModel, newdata = iris, type = 'response')

myResults <- cbind(iris, myPreds)

myResults %>% 
  mutate(
    pred_binary = case_when(
      myPreds > 0.5 ~ 1,
      myPreds <= 0.5 ~ 0
      ),
    correct = case_when(
      Species_to_predict == pred_binary ~ "Correct",
      TRUE ~ "Incorrect"
      )
    ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = pred_binary, color = correct)) +
  geom_jitter() +
  theme_bw()
```

How can I add the text to the `ggplot` which will count the number of points in each quadrant of the confusion matrix?

Comment: An aside: you don't need `case_when` to create a binary variable like `Species_to_predict`, since all you're doing is testing that it is or isn't equal to virginica. `Species_to_predict = as.numeric(Species == "virginica")` or `Species_to_predict = +(Species == "virginica")` would suffice. Imagine you had an odd case in the data that you didn't spell out in your `case_when`. Similar applies to the ones below

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I thought I might have run into some problems when passing a character variable to the `glm` function. (I just tried it now and it seems like I can pass the `Species` variable to the `glm` function).

Comment: You'll still be passing the same values to `glm`, it's just clearer and more concise (and possible safer) to create a numeric value from a logical one when all you're doing is making a binary variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the cleaner creation of binary variables I mentioned in comments, I'd recommend doing some preprocessing and aggregation before plotting, rather than doing it as you're creating the plot. You can add the predicted values in a `mutate` call and save that, along with the binaries, to a data frame (`iris_predicted`). Then count how many points are in the quadrants, which are based on `Species` and `pred_binary`.

I moved the color assignment to just apply to points so the text would be black; you could change this and keep the `correct` column in the aggregation if you want, although it would become hard to read the text in the chart.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

iris2 <- iris %>%
  filter(Species != "setosa") %>%
  mutate(Species_to_predict = +(Species == "virginica"))

myLogitModel <- glm(formula = Species_to_predict ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width,
                    data = iris2, family = "binomial")

iris_predicted <- iris2 %>%
  mutate(myPreds = predict(myLogitModel, newdata = ., type = "response"),
         pred_binary = +(myPreds > 0.5),
         correct = ifelse(Species_to_predict == pred_binary, "Correct", "Incorrect"))
iris_counts <- iris_predicted %>%
  count(Species, pred_binary)

ggplot(iris_predicted, aes(x = Species, y = pred_binary)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(color = correct)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = n), data = iris_counts) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]